# How to get the type of an instance of javax.lang.model.element.Element

Tags: kotlin, kotlinpoet

I'm following [Hello World of Annotation Processing in Kotlin](https://medium.com/@Miqubel/hello-world-of-annotation-processing-in-kotlin-3ec0290c1fdd) and [KotlinPoet's documentation](https://github.com/square/kotlinpoet) and am trying to implement a generic builder for Kotlin. I'd like to generically create a method for every field in an annotated data class and give it's argument the same name and type of the field. The problem is that I cannot find which type the field has, given the instance of `javax.lang.model.element.Element` that I have. Here's what I managed that far:

```
fieldsIn(klass.enclosedElements)
            .forEach {
                classBuilder
                        .addProperty(PropertySpec
                                .builder(it.toString(), String::class, KModifier.INTERNAL)
                                .mutable(true)
                                .initializer("\"\"")
                                .build())

                classBuilder
                        .addFunction(FunSpec
                                .builder(it.toString())
                                .addParameter(ParameterSpec
                                        .builder(
                                                it.toString(), 
                                                it.?) // what to use here?
                                        .build())
                                .build())
            }
```

How can I find the type of the field? I read in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/Element.html#asType()) that you should use method `asType()` but this return an instance of `TypeMirror`. I can't really see how to continue from here. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using this function:

```
private fun getClass(it: VariableElement): KClass<*> {
    val type = it.asType()

    return when (type.kind) {
        TypeKind.DECLARED -> Class.forName(type.toString()).kotlin
        TypeKind.BOOLEAN -> Boolean::class
        TypeKind.BYTE -> Byte::class
        TypeKind.SHORT -> Short::class
        TypeKind.INT -> Int::class
        TypeKind.LONG -> Long::class
        TypeKind.CHAR -> Char::class
        TypeKind.FLOAT -> Float::class
        TypeKind.DOUBLE -> Double::class
        else -> throw Exception("Unknown type: $type, kind: ${type.kind}")
    }
}
```

Comment: How to get whether the type is nullable or non-nullable? For eg, how to know whether the type of variable is "String?" or "String"

Comment: What about parameterized types like `List<Something>` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
.addMember("%N", "${it.asType()}::class")
```

Comment: you need to add some explanation. Posting the code only might not be helpful

Comment: The problem is to get cKlass from type, which is possible to do as described in  authors answer, but Class.forName() will work only if your processor module is aware about the cKlass you're trying to create. In my situation it is not the case, but a workaround with setting name "%N" instead of type "%T" and just adding a "::class" string - worked.